# How to write in new file if are occurrences in another one?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, ksh

I need to create and write in a new file based in occurrences found in another file. i.e:

```
Occurrence found in first file
then write same Occurrence in another one/new
```

to be more specific:

### "File1": to find Occurrences:

```
Occurrence1
Occurrence2
OccurrenceN

##If the `Occurence1` is find in `File1` then write in the `new file` the same Occurrence
```

I have the next functional command in `ksh` to specify the occurrences in the file and how many not:

```
users=(Occurrence1 Occurrence2 Occurrence3 Occurrence4 ... OccurrenceN)
for i in "${users[@]}"
do
grep -qw $i file1 && echo "$i is in the file" || echo "$i is not in the file"
done
```

I make some modification to the early code:

```
users=(Occurrence1 Occurrence2 Occurrence3 ... OccurrenceN)
for i in "${users[@]}"
do
        grep -qw $i File1.txt && echo "$i is in the file" || echo "$i is not in the file"
       if [[ $user = "*is in the file" ]]; then
       echo $user >> users_in_file.txt
       elif [[ $user = "*is not in the file" ]]; then
       echo $user >> users_not_in_file.txt
       fi
done
```

I have idea to implement the last command to take my objective, but is not working. Is there another one to make it?
Thanks in advance. Any doubt please post like a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep` directly as the condition of the `if`, and proceed accordingly:

```
users=(Occurrence1 Occurrence2 Occurrence13  OccurrenceN)
for i in "${users[@]}"
do
       if grep -qw "$i" File1.txt; then
                echo "$i is in the file"
                echo "$i" >> users_in_file.txt
       else
                echo "$i is not in the file"
                echo "$i" >> users_not_in_file.txt
       fi
done
```

Comment: I have a question, is there any way to make a conditional with the output command? in this case "is in the file" or "is not in the file" to make some separations.

Comment: @Mareyes output (echo) we get is after the conditional (if), then may I know why do we need to make another condition from the output?